# Passing variable to component AngularJS

Tags: angular, variables, dependencies, components

I am currently working on a school project and almost have my program fully functioning. The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to pass collected user data from one component into the next component to display it in the profile page. I've tried some things with @Input() and such but feel as if I'm better off asking here and actually learning something than getting it right on a guess.

```
login( username, password ) {
    //returns succes/error
    //return data
    console.log(username, password)
    const url = `https://svsdb.woodl.nl:5555/api/public/auth/login`;
    const data = {
      email: username,
      password: password,
    }
    console.log(data)
    this.httpClient.post(url, data).subscribe(
      (res:any)=>{
        console.log(res)
        console.log(res.message)
        this.token = res.data.token.value
        this.readUser(res.data.user._id)
        this.key = res.message
      },
      (error)=>console.log(error),
      ()=>console.log(),
    )
  }

  readUser(userId) {
    const url = `https://svsdb.woodl.nl:5555/api/user/read/${userId}`;
    const options = {
      headers: {
        authorization: this.token,
      }
    }
    this.httpClient.get(url, options).subscribe(
      (res:any)=>{
        console.log(res)
        const user_data = res
        console.log(this.key)
        this.redirect(this.key)
      },
      (error)=>{

      },
      ()=>{

      }
    )
  }
```

These two functions are part of the LoginComponent, the data I want to pass to my ProfileComponent is the 'user_data' that I retrieve in the second function.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css'],
  providers: [ LoginComponent ]
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(
    private loginComponent: LoginComponent
  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    const user_data = this.loginComponent.user_data;
  }

}
```

This is my whole profilecomponent.ts file, as you can see I tried to retrieve the user data but this isn't working, I am very new to all this and this is the final step to finishing my assignment so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: perhaps this will help you: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: basically, since you are trying to share data from one view do another, you need a place to store it.  as MarkB mentions below, you could create a service for this.

Comment: you could also stash it in `localStorage`

Answer (score 0):

I like using rxjs' behaviorsubject to do things like having a different component display the information called from another.  I recommend getting the data in a service.  Call the function in that service from one component and display in another.
Here is an example of doing a search from the navbar component, runs the function in the service to get the data, and the data gets displayed in the view component.

The service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
   private _data = new BehaviorSubject (null);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private messageService : MessageService) { }

  getData(page:number){
    return this.http.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/"+page)
    .subscribe(data => this._data.next(data));
  }


  get data$() {
  return this._data.asObservable();
 }
}
```

This component is where I call the function get the data, here it was my navbar component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../data.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }
  page:number;

  search(page){
    this.dataService.getData(page);
  }

 ngOnInit() {
 }

}
```

Then the data gets displayed in the view component:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../data.service';
import * as Rx from "rxjs";


@Component({
 selector: 'app-view',
 templateUrl: './view.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./view.component.css']
})
export class ViewComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit  {
sub: Rx.Subscription;
info:{};

constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

ngOnInit(){
 this.sub = this.dataService.data$.subscribe(data=>this.info=data);
}

ngOnDestroy () {
 this.sub.unsubscribe();
 }
}
```

Does this give you any ideas to try in your app?